# Integrability of the Jacobi Theta Function

Tags: riemann-zeta, absolute-convergence, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $$\psi(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} e^{-n^{2} \pi x}$$ be a theta function. Can it be shown that that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \psi(x) \cdot dx < \infty$$ without invoking Fubini-Tonelli’s Theorem about interchanging the sum and integral? If so, this would be a way to prove Riemann’s functional equation,
$$\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s) = \pi^{(1-s)/2}\Gamma((1-s)/2)\zeta(1-s)$$ using only the dominated convergence theorem and properties of the theta function described above.

Comment: The fact that when $f_n\geq 0$ you can interchange the series with the integral $\int_{X}\sum_{n}f_n\,d\mu=\sum_{n}\int_Xf_n\,d\mu$ is a corollary of Fubini-Tonelli when $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. But you can also apply dominated convergence to the partial sums $F_N=\sum_{n=1}^Nf_n$ (note that since $f_n\geq 0$, the sequence $F_N$ is increasing, thus has a limit $F$, namely the supremum, and in your case, this is finite due to exponentially decaying terms), and this argument holds  even when $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite. So yes, swapping series with integrals is a corollary of DCT.

Comment: Sorry actually we should use monotone convergence theorem directly in the non-negative case. This will show $F$ is an integrable doninating function. In the signed/complex case we then put absolute values everywhere and then we appeal to dominated convergence.

Comment: @peek-a-boo okay; I understand the reasoning, but how do I know that the limit $F$ is integrable?

Comment: Monotone convergence justifies the interchange. Then integrating term-by-term gives you a finite result due to the $1/n^2$ decay. So $F$ (in your case $\psi$) is integrable.

Comment: @peek-a-boo okay. Yes, just looked up monotone convergence theorem now. Thank you!